# *minimal, fast* least-squares function for python

Tags: python, least-squares

Is there a pre-existing library that does the equivalent of

```
B = np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X) @ X.T @ y
return B
```

and nothing else??  I want something fast and minimal (i.e.: no pvalues, no standard errors).  Obviously I've already done it above, but I don't want to write my own unit tests or handle all the corner cases :)

Comment: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html <--- does this fit the bill?

Comment: @Mouse that one is my go-to for interactive work.  but it does lots of stuff that I don't need when `fit` is called.  For example, it computes the parameter covariance matrix.  I'm trying to get this code to run fast and I want to strip away anything but the computation of the parameter vector.

Comment: ah yes sorry you're completely correct. Perhaps this is better https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html

Comment: (similar version in SciPy) https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html#scipy.linalg.lstsq

Comment: Oh, thanks.  I passed over this one initially because they use `x` to denote the parameters and I thought they were solving some other problem.  Weirdos!

Answer (score 2):

[`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) part of python's standard library has

> [`statistics.linear_regression(x, y, /, *, proportional=False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.linear_regression)
>
> Return the slope and intercept of simple linear regression parameters
> estimated using ordinary least squares.(...)

However, there is catch that it is

> New in version 3.10.

Thus you must not use it, if you are bound to support older versions.

I am not sure if it does satisfy your *fast* requirement, but looking at [source of `statistics`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/statistics.py) it seems to be *minimal*, in sense that it does only things required to get values to return.